# Trying to combine this queries into one, because I want to write queries without using temp table. Keep getting syntax error

Tags: sql, casting, temp-tables, subquery

```
    SELECT
          CAST([patientDATA] AS XML).value('PatientcardCard[1]/Replacements[1]/patientId[1]', 'nvarchar(80)') [patientId]
        ,* into #tmp
        FROM hospital [c1] with(NOLOCK)
        where
        patientserial in (
        select ptserial From patients with(Nolock)
        where patientsid=6889
        and patientprogramid in (
        26917,
        21296,
        27025
        )
        )
    
    

    select patientId,patientbarcode,patientprogramID
    into #tmp1
    From #tmp
    join patients with(nolock) on patientserial=ptserial
    where patientid in
    ('0401478300007847',
    '0401478300008566',
    '0401478300008761',
    '0401478300008727',
    '0401478300007648',
    '0401478300008020'
)
```

So first query is using cast to get value from a tag inside a column, the tag is patientID, and it is storing data into a temp table.

The second query is pulling the data from the temp table. I want to write a nested query without using temp table. But I keep syntax error, this is my query so far:

```
select patientId,patientbarcode,patientprogramID
        
        From (
 SELECT
          CAST([patientDATA] AS XML).value('PatientcardCard[1]/Replacements[1]/patientId[1]', 'nvarchar(80)') [patientId]
        ,* into #tmp
        FROM hospital [c1] with(NOLOCK)
        where
        patientserial in (
        select ptserial From patients with(Nolock)
        where patientsid=6889
        and patientprogramid in (
        26917,
        21296,
        27025
        )
        )



)
        join patients with(nolock) on patientserial=ptserial
        where patientid in
        ('0401478300007847',
        '0401478300008566',
        '0401478300008761',
        '0401478300008727',
        '0401478300007648',
        '0401478300008020'
    )
```

My error in SQL:

```
invalid column in first line, around patientId,patientbarcode


and in join part, invalid column as ptserial
```

Is it because the value is casted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some problems with your approach.

1. `SELECT *` is not a good idea.  It also appears to be unnecessary
   for your final query.
2. You should reference which table each column
   is coming from.
3. You may be overthinking this.

```
SELECT CAST([patientDATA] AS XML).value('PatientcardCard[1]/Replacements[1]/patientId[1]', 'nvarchar(80)') [patientId]
, patientbarcode
, patiendprogramID

FROM hospital h
    INNER JOIN patients p ON p.ptserial = h.patientserial

WHERE patientsid = 6889
  AND patientprogramid IN (26917, 21296, 27025)
  AND patientid IN (
        '0401478300007847'
        ,'0401478300008566'
        ,'0401478300008761'
        ,'0401478300008727'
        ,'0401478300007648'
        ,'0401478300008020'
        )
```

Comment: I still get invalid error in patientID(last lines), is it because I casted that data?

Comment: I don't know what an "invalid error" is.  Do you mean invalid column reference or some such thing?  You shouldn't have `AND patientid IN`.  You should reference the table alias, like `AND p.patientid IN`.  I didn't do that because I don't know which table contains which columns because you didn't provide that information.